# Installed CLI Tool in Default Path Not Available?

Tags: command-line

I tried to install rtmpdump, and found it in the CLI default path, using

```
sudo find / -iname "rtmpdump"
```

I *did* get a result:

```
/usr/local/bin/rtmpdump
```

which *is* one of the default paths.

However, when I tried to execute the command, I got:

```
-bash: rtmpdump: command not found
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo `$PATH` to be sure that `/usr/local/bin/` is in it. And see the permissions of the file by `ls -l` - maybe you are not allowed to read/execute it.